# Simple Weather API Current Temperature Not Working

Tags: jquery, json, api, weather

I'm new to JavaScript and jquery... I have been trying to write a simple piece of code to alert the current temperature using a weather api.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>

 <script>
 var my_city="Washington,USA";
 var my_key="8b0642a6c7133932132002";
 var no_of_days=2;
 // build URI:
 var uri="http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?               q="+my_city+"&key="+my_key+"&format=json&no_of_days="+no_of_days+"&includeLocation=yes";
 // uri-encode it to prevent errors :
 uri=encodeURI(uri); 

 jQuery.get(uri,function(r){
 current_temp_C  =r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
 alert(current_temp_C);
 },"json");
 </script>
```

However, nothing is displayed. If anyone can point me to where I'm going wrong, please tell me! 
Thanks!

Comment: There are other resources for weather that have demo code http://codepen.io/jamesfleeting/pen/wHism

Comment: Great demo Shanimal, but I was more aiming for just the text for the current temperature. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example from another http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvyDh

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are ending up in the error handler, and you are only taking care of successfull ajax calls in your code. Since you are using jquery > 1.5, you could do something like this to check:

```
jQuery.get(uri,function(r){
    current_temp_C  =r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
     alert(current_temp_C);
},"json").fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOpts, thrownError){
    alert(thrownError);
});
```

Also, you query string has a lot of spaces according to the code. Instead of passing the data as a custom querystring, add an object literal with the data as a second ardument to `$.get`:

```
jQuery.get(uri, { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, function(r){
//etc...
```

Comment: @InfiniDaZa If you elaborate "no luck" I could try to help you